# dimension of $M = \{ x \in \mathbb{C}^{n} \ | \ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i=0 \}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, independence

What is the dimension of $M = \{ x \in \mathbb{C}^n \ | \ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i=0 \}$?

**New Attempt**:
Let $f$ be the linear map $f: \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$, then we notice that $\ker f = M$. By the rank theorem we have: $\text{rg}(f) + \ker{f}= \dim{\mathbb{C}^n} $, thus $\dim{M} = n - \dim{\mathbb{C}} = n -1 $. Is this right?

Comment: Seems hand-wavy. Linear independence applies to sets of vectors, not to a single arbitrary vector satisfying the sum condition. You should either come up with a basis, or more elegantly, recognise $M$ as the kernel of a linear map and use the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: Every linear relation reduces by one the dimension.

Comment: @TheoBendit I've tried a proof using your hint, could you say me if it is right? Thanks!

Comment: @vitalmath Yes, that is correct. You could improve it a little by justifying why the range of $f$ is indeed all of $\Bbb{C}$ (by taking arbitrary $z \in \Bbb{C}$ and finding a vector $v \in \Bbb{C}^n$ such that $f(v) = z$), or at least that the rank of $f$ is $1$ (which you can do by arguing from the fact that $f$ is not the zero map).

Comment: If we take $v = (z,0,\dots,0)$, it should be fine no?

Comment: @vitalmath Yes, indeed that would work.

Comment: Is $M$ a set or a number?

Comment: @TedShifrin Changed it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let $(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n})$ be an arbitrary vector in $M$. such that $x_{i}\in \mathbb{C}$

Then $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}=0$ so $x_{n}=-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_{i}$

So it is $(x_{1},x_{2},....,-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_{i}) = x_{1}(1,0,...0,-1)+x_{2}(0,1,...0,-1)+...+x_{n-1}(0,0,...1,-1)$

So $$M=span\left(\left\{(1,0,...0,-1),(0,1,...0,-1),...,(0,0,...1,-1)\right\}\right)$$

The above set $\left\{(1,0,...0,-1),(0,1,...0,-1),...,(0,0,...1,-1)\right\}$ is a basis for $M$ and clearly $M$ has dimension $n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Right. A basis is given by the $n-1$ vectors (as rows)

$(1,0,\ldots,0,-1), (0,1,0,\ldots, 0,-1),\ldots, (0,\ldots,0,,1,-1)$.

Comment: The nth coordinate should have a $-1$.